# Do we have $[E : K]_i = [E_r : K]$ where $E_r$ is purely inseparable closure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $E/K$ be an algebraic extension.
Let $E_s$ (resp. $E_r$) be the set of elements of $E$ which are separable (resp. purely inseparable) over $K$.
Let $[E : K]_i = [E : E_s] = \frac{[E : K]}{[E : K]_s}$ be the inseparable degree.
Do we have $[E : K]_i = [E_r : K]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$k=\Bbb{F}_3,K=k(x^6,y^6),E=K(x+y^2),L=K(x^3)=K(x^3+y^6)$.

$L/K$ is a separable quadratic extension, $E/L$ is purely inseparable of degree $3$ and $[E:K]=6$.

If there is $E/F/K$ with $F/K$ purely inseparable then $[F:K]=3,[E:F]=2$.

Let $f\in F[T]$ be the degree 2 minimal polynomial of $x+y^2$.

$f$ stays irreducible over $k(x^2,y^2)\supset F$ so in fact $f=(T-x-y^2)(T+x-y^2)= T^2-2y^2 T-x^2+y^4$ whence $y^2,x^2\in F$ which is a contradiction as $k(x^2,y^2)$ has degree $3^2$ over $K$.